# Simple Swift function return error

Tags: macos, swift

I am converting some algorithm pseudo code to Swift and have the following function:

```
func max(a: [Int], b: Int) {

  var result = a[0]

  var i: Int

  for (i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
      if (a[i] > result) {
          result = a[i]
      }
  }
  return result
}
```

I get an error when returning the result: 'Int' is not convertible to '()'

I've had a search online and can't find an answer to this question and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note for clarity, since your first function parameter `a` (the Array of Int) is not modified in the function call it should not be declared as `inout`.

Comment: Thanks JMFR - I am still trying to get to grips with inout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type is missing in the function declaration:

```
func max(inout a: [Int], b: Int) -> Int {
                                 ^^^^^^
```

Without a return type, swift defaults to an empty tuple `()`, and that's what the error means: int is not convertible to an empty tuple.

Also note that your `return` statement is misplaced: it should go right before the last closing bracket

```
    }
    return result
}
```

and not

```
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must Implement the return type like this

```
 func max(inout a: [Int], b: Int)-> Int {

 var result = a[0]
 var i: Int

 for (i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
  if (a[i] > result) {
      result = a[i]
  }
 }
 return result
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that your first example is valid swift. Can you share where in the documentation it states that you can omit the return arrow `->`?